# Highcharts - Disable the legend of secondary y axis by default

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I wanted to disable the Secondary yaxis legend to be disabled by default. User can then click on the legend to enable it on the chart.

Example :
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        enable: false,
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mb',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
            'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mb'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' °C'
        }
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    floating: false,
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                yAxis: [{
                    labels: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: 0,
                        y: -6
                    },
                    showLastLabel: false
                }, {
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 0,
                        y: -6
                    },
                    showLastLabel: false
                }, {
                    visible: false
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

In this example, secondary yaxis label "Rainfall" is enabled by default.
What Im looking for is disabled "Rainfall" by default. User can then click on it and enable it.

Here's what I am looking for:
[Rainfall is disabled here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6ocu.png)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

We can just pass "visible: false" in the data series. This will disable the series by default.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-visible/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        visible: false
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```